# How to randomize different values in a loop? c++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, random

I want to assign different -random- values (index) to populate a vector.
Each time I run the program, it produces a different random value. But, it produces the same random value in each iteration of the loop for the same run.

this is my code :

```
  void hire (vector<PersonType> &salaryMan, vector<CompanyType> &company){

            double payment;
            string role;
            int i;
            int j;

            for (int x =0; x <5; x++){

                i =randomizeEmp(salaryMan);
                payment =salaryMan[i].getSalary();
                role =salaryMan[i].getTitle();      
                j =randomizeEmp(salaryMan);
                salaryMan[j].setTitle(role);
                salaryMan[j].setSalary(payment);
                company[x].employee.push_back(salaryMan[j]);
            }
        }

  int randomizeEmp(vector<PersonType> &v){
            double i;
            int minNumOfEmp =0;
            unsigned seed =time(NULL);
            srand(seed);
            i =minNumOfEmp +rand()% ((v.size()-1) - minNumOfEmp);
            cout <<i<<endl;
            return i;
        }
```

My output is the following:
CompanyA    Florida Miami   100 
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
CompanyB    NewYork NewYork 101 
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
CompanyC    California  SanJose 102 
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
CompanyD    Texas   Dallas  103 
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
CompanyE    Florida Talahasse   104 
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000
    Linette Lefevers    529 PartnerG    600000

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned seed = time(NULL);
srand(seed);
```

This is something you generally want to do *once,* when your program starts.

Every time you do it within the same second (and a *lot* happens in under a second in the computer world<sup>(a)</sup>), it will restart the sequence at the same point.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> *One* of the things that's likely to take well under a second is that five-iteration, not-much-work-involved, `for` loop in your `hire()` function. Hence probably *every* iteration of it will use the same seed.